# Unable to initialise LimitedWebPartManager due to ServerRelativeUrl error

Tags: development, csom

I am simply trying to get a list of all web parts on a page so that I can find the correct ID for the zone which they sit in.

The url to the page looks like this

[image]

Here is my code (Where `Url` contains the value up to the end of the blue line in the image):

```
using (_clientContext = new ClientContext(Url))
{
    _clientContext.Credentials = _credentials;
    var web = _clientContext.Web;

    var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("SitePages/Home.aspx");
    var limitedWebPartManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var webPart in limitedWebPartManager.WebParts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(webPart.WebPart.ZoneIndex);
    }

    var webPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart(_scriptEditorXml);
    limitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(webPartDefinition.WebPart, "", 0);
}
```

I just keep getting

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'serverRelativeUrl
>   Parameter name: Specified value is not supported for the serverRelativeUrl parameter.'

On the `ExecuteQuery()` line, and I can't work out why.

Is there any reason why it is so difficult to work out the ID of a zone (which I need to insert a web part?)

I tried adding `/` before my ServerRelativeUrl param, but then I got

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl'

These error messages seem really unhelpful to me - maybe someone can shed some light on what I am meant to do with this information?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to pass the `ServerRelativeUrl` in the `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` method.

The value that you are passing, `SitePages/Home.aspx`, will not work, it needs to be something like `/sites/test/subsite/SitePages/Home.aspx`. So, you can get the `ServerRelativeUrl` of the current web using the `web.ServerRelativeUrl` property and then form your string.

Modify your code as below:

```
string Url = "https://sitecollectionurl/sites/test/subsite";
using (_clientContext = new ClientContext(Url))
{
    _clientContext.Credentials = _credentials;
    var web = _clientContext.Web;   

    _clientContext.Load(web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SitePages/Home.aspx");
    var limitedWebPartManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    // more code
}
```